# How to organize a Java class to store SQL table with a composite key?

Tags: java, sql, data-structures

An SQL table with a compound primary key stores some data. `ID`, `TYPE` and `PAGE` form a composite key, while VAL1 and VAL2 store values.

[image]

I want to create a class that has `String name; String val1; String val2;`, populate instances and do conversion between the SQL table and a collection of instances of the class. What would be a good implementation if such a class? I am choosing between these options:

(1) A `class Page` that extends `abstract class Type` that extends `abstract class ID`, but this seems unnatural.

(2) Concatenate ID, TYPE and PAGE, but then first and second entries will clash. Concatenation with special characters like `12_11_2` would cause troubles with escaping these characters in the strings down the road.

(3) A class with five strings (one per each column) seems unnatural, because then I don't have a unique handle like `String compositeKey;`

What is the most efficient way to turn SQL table with a composite key into a collection of instances of a class?

Comment: In JPA one uses separate class for the composite key, so I guess it;s a fine approach. So you shoudl use `composition` not inheritance like in (1). (2) sux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TreeMap` with a class `MyKey` (string A; String B; String C;) as a key and class MyValue (String D; String E) as the value.